Remove single controller from `ConfigureApplicationPartManager` in ASP.NET Core
I'm aware that _mvcBuilder.ConfigureApplicationPartManager allows me to remove complete assemblies from the AppParts (remove all controllers of one assembly). But is there a possibility to remove only a single controller?
I'd like to be able to control what ASP.NET Core MVC controllers of my library are available via settings.

Hi @tris, can you share what's the version of .net core?

You can selectively remove individual controllers in ASP.NET Core by customizing the IApplicationFeatureProvider:
public class CustomControllerFeatureProvider : IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature>
{
    private readonly HashSet<Type> _excludedControllers;

    public CustomControllerFeatureProvider(IEnumerable<Type> excludedControllers)
    {
        _excludedControllers = new HashSet<Type>(excludedControllers);
    }

    public void PopulateFeature(IEnumerable<ApplicationPart> parts, ControllerFeature feature)
    {
        // Remove controllers that match the types in _excludedControllers
        feature.Controllers
            .Where(controller => _excludedControllers.Contains(controller.AsType()))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(controller => feature.Controllers.Remove(controller));
    }
}

In Program.cs, configure the ApplicationPartManager to use your custom feature provider:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Assume we have a setting that tells us which controllers to exclude
var excludedControllers = new List<Type>
{
            typeof(YourNamespace.Controllers.YourController) // Specify the controller type to exclude
        };

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().ConfigureApplicationPartManager(partManager =>
{
    partManager.FeatureProviders.Add(new CustomControllerFeatureProvider(excludedControllers));
});


Haven't checked it yet, going to tomorrow. But answer already feels totally perfect, thank you!
